# Pyenv listed version not found

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I have Python 3.9.6 installed on my machine, along with 3.6.5, the two of which I use for different projects. At least that is the idea. However, when I run the command `pyenv global 3.9.6`,  I get the response `3.9.6 not installed`,

I do find python@3.9/3.9.6 in my Library folder. What's going on here, what's a good way to switch environments please?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `pyenv versions` in order to identify the Versions Installed.

If it is not installed you can use pyenv install.

To ask your question:

-Use `pyenv install -l` in order to see the curent available version that can be installed. Python 3.9.6 it is not one of them!

You did not install with pyenv Python 3.9.6, it cannot be installed with pyenv. That is the reason you cannot use it.

Comment: `pyenv install --list |grep 3.9
  3.9.0
  3.9-dev
  3.9.1
  3.9.2
  3.9.3
  3.9.4
  3.9.5
  3.9.6
  miniconda-3.9.1
  miniconda3-3.9.1
  miniconda3-3.9-4.9.2
 pyenv global 3.9.5            
pyenv: version `3.9.5' not installed`

Comment: Sorry, my copy paste seems to get rid of newline character, but I do have 3.9.5 and 3.9.6 installed as shown in the `pyenv install --list` command, which I mentioned in the question above.

Comment: `pyenv install --list` is showing you the versions that pyenv could install, not the versions it did install. `pyenv versions` will tell you which versions are managed by pyenv.